# Copy 1D array to a row of a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

```java
int n = 5;
int[] oneD = new int[5];
int[] oneD2 = new int[5];
int[] oneD3 = new int[5];
.
.
.
n

int[][] twoD = new int[n][5];
```

How can the three oned arrays in java can be copied to seperate rows of the 2D array? *Actually,* is there some short and lovely handy feature in *java 8+* to do so?

Comment: Are you able to just initialize the 2-d array without having to create n 1-d arrays?

Comment: Yup, I could do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options:

1. Don't "copy" the arrays, use them:

   ```java
   int[][] twod = new int[][] { oned, oned2, oned3 };
   ```

   OR:

   ```java
   twod[0] = oned;
   twod[1] = oned2;
   twod[2] = oned3;
   ```

   E.g. `twod[1][3]` and `oned2[3]` now refer to the same value, so changing one changes the other.
2. Copy the array contents:

   ```java
   System.arraycopy(oned, 0, twod[0], 0, 5);
   System.arraycopy(oned2, 0, twod[1], 0, 5);
   System.arraycopy(oned3, 0, twod[2], 0, 5);
   ```

   `twod` is now entirely independent of the other arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Java 8 solution.  It simply creates new arrays and combines them into a 2D array. The 2D arrays are independent of the originals.  Thanks to [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63365224/1552534) for the `int[]::clone` tip.

```
int n = 5;
int[] oned = new int[5];
int[] oned2 = new int[5];
int[] oned3 = new int[5];
.
.
.
n

int[][] twod = Stream.of(oned, oned2, oned3,...,onedn)
        .map(int[]::clone)
        .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

Comment: `Arrays.stream(arr).toArray()` → `Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length)`

Comment: Definitely better.  Made the change.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I just remembered: `Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length)` → `arr.clone()`, or even better, use method reference `map(int[]::clone)`. Since array types cannot be subclassed, using `clone()` is perfectly safe.